# split data in a single row into multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to split a comma separated field into multiple records based on ','

[image]

Comment: CHARINDEX is what you want

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "I need" and an image of data is not a question. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youll want to use string_split like this:

```
select t.S.No, x.Value
from yourTable t
CROSS APPLY  string_split(Char, ',') x
```

Comment: This would be better, but assumes Compatibility level 130

Comment: fair enough i guess